# Tensorflow/Keras custom loss function

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I want to create a custom loss function in keras.

Let's say I have yTrue and yPred which are tensors (n x m) of true and predicted labels.

Let's call each sample n (that is, each row in yTrue and yPred)  yT and yP.
Then I want a loss function that computes (yT-yP)^2 when yT[0] == 1, otherwise it will compute (yT[0]-yP[0])^2.

**That is: for each sample I always want to calculate the squared error for the first element  - but I want to calculate the squared error of the other elements only if the first element of the true label == 1.**

How do I do this in a custom loss function?

This is what I have gotten so far:

I need to do this with tensors operations. 
First I can compute

```
Y = (yTrue - yPred)^2
```

Then I can define a masking matrix where the first column is always one, and the others are 1 depending on the value of the first element for each row of yTrue. 
So I can get something like

```
1 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 
1 0 0 0 0
```

I can then multiply element wise this matrix with Y and obtain what I want.

However, how do I get in generating the masking matrix? In particular, how do I do the condition "if the first element of the row is 1" in tensorflow/keras?

Maybe there is a better way to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a conditional switch `K.switch` in the backend. Something along the lines of:

```
mse = K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1) # standard mse
msep = K.square(y_pred[:,0] - y_true[:,0])
return K.switch(K.equals(y_true[:,0], 1), mse, msep)
```

Edit for handling per sample condition.

Comment: Thank you, but the condition is not about the first element of the first sample (y_true[0,0]) must be applied for _each_ sample. 
Do you think
mse = K.mean(K.square(yPred - yTrue), axis=-1) ; msep = K.square(yTrue[:, 0] - yPred[:, 0]) ; return K.switch(K.equal(yTrue[:, 0], 1), mse, msep)   
would work? It does compile, but is difficult to understand if it's doing what I want it to do!

Comment: Ah that is slightly different but it should work because the keras [backend](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/e8fad1be1c1187926a02a35b7f25bc6ab7732699/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L2943) actually checks for higher dimensional conditionals.